# How to Override Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals.php?

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides

I want to override Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals this block I did but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals" type="EC\InStorePickupTax\Block\Adminhtml\Totals"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Vendor]/Block/Adminhtml/Totals.php`

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Vendor]\Block\Adminhtml;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals
{
    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        $this->_totals = [];
        $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'subtotal',
                'value' => $this->getSource()->getSubtotal(),
                'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseSubtotal(),
                'label' => __('Subtotal'),
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Add shipping
         */
        if (!$this->getSource()->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$this->getSource()->getShippingAmount() ||
            $this->getSource()->getShippingDescription())
        ) {
            $shippingLabel = __('Shipping & Handling');
            if ($this->isFreeShipping($this->getOrder()) && $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $shippingLabel .= sprintf(' (%s)', $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription());
            }
            $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'shipping',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseShippingAmount(),
                    'label' => $shippingLabel,
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add discount
         */
        if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0) {
            if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount');
            }
            $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }

        if($this->getOrder()->getShippingMethod() == 'flatrate_flatrate'){
            $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'grand_total',
                    'strong' => true,
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->getGrandTotal(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getOrder()->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total'),
                    'area' => 'footer',
                ]
            );
        }else{
            $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'grand_total',
                    'strong' => true,
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getGrandTotal(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total'),
                    'area' => 'footer',
                ]
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Also I also override `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer` block, it's working but I know why another block is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, Basically there is a `Block` **`Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals.php`** which extends **`Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals`**, so I override this block `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals.php`

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals" type="EC\InStorePickupTax\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Invoice/Totals.php`

```
<?php

namespace EC\InStorePickupTax\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals
{
    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();

        if($this->getOrder()->getShippingMethod() == 'flatrate_flatrate'){
            $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'grand_total',
                    'strong' => true,
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->getGrandTotal(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getOrder()->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total'),
                    'area' => 'footer',
                ]
            );
        }else{
            $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'grand_total',
                    'strong' => true,
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getGrandTotal(),
                    'base_value' => $this->getSource()->getBaseGrandTotal(),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total'),
                    'area' => 'footer',
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try calling the parent constructor to ensure all class dependencies are loaded as expected.

Comment: I think i found my solution, `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals.php` is extending `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Totals`, now I'm trying to override `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Totals.php` lets see.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this solution for Magento v-2.3.5

**Override this class \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals**

app/code/Taktheer/ExtendCoupanTotals/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" type="Taktheer\ExtendCoupanTotals\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Taktheer/ExtendCoupanTotals/Rewrite/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Totals.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Unyscape Infocom Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


   declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Taktheer\ExtendCoupanTotals\Rewrite\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals
{
      /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        
        $order = $this->getSource();
        
        if ($order->getCouponCode()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $order->getCouponCode());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'value' => $order->getDiscountAmount(),
                'base_value' => $order->getBaseDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
       

     ]
        );
        return $this;
    }

}
```

======================== Happy Coding =============================